# Ambari server installation on centos7.4 get repos error

Tags: cluster-computing, ambari

I'm trying to get my own cluster with Ambari following this official guide https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Quick+Start+Guide#space-menu-link-content. But I cannot copy repository on this command `wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/ambari.repo http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos7/2.x/updates/2.5.1.0/ambari.repo`
I am using centos7.4

As a result I have problem 403:Forbidden. I also tried to get this page via browser but I got an error.

I also tried to use one of this repos https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.2.0.0/bk_Installing_HDP_AMB/content/_ambari_repositories.html or similar but there's still nothing.
Could you help me guys?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Effective Jan 31, 2021, all Cloudera software requires a subscription and must be accessed via the paywall", please check https://www.cloudera.com/downloads.html